# mongoose find in document object

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Lets say I have a mongoose schema, something like:

```
mongoose.Schema({
website_id:mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
data:Object
})
```

where **data** field contains JSON Object. Something like:

```
{
   "actions":[
      {
         "action":"pageChange",
         "url":"http://localhost:3000/login",
         "dom":"",
         "timestamp":1653341614846
      },
      {
         "action":"pageChange",
         "url":"http://localhost:3000/signup",
         "dom":"",
         "timestamp":1653341626442
      },
      {
         "action":"pageChange",
         "url":"http://localhost:3000/view",
         "dom":"",
         "timestamp":1653341626442
      },
      {
         "action":"pageChange",
         "url":"http://localhost:3000/login",
         "dom":"",
         "timestamp":1653341626442
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there any way I can get all documents, where **data field object** contains **http://localhost:3000/login** as url, without getting all the documents first and looping them through.

Object is going to be dynamic generated, and items will repeat themselves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, there are several ways and in this case, one of the best ways is to use "aggregate"

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
   {$unwind: "$actions"},
   { $match: {"actions.url": "http://localhost:3000/login"}},
   {$group: {
     _id: "$_id",
     actions: {$push: "$actions"}
     }
   }
 ])
```

return Response :

```
{
 "actions": [
   {
    "action": "pageChange",
    "dom": "",
    "timestamp": 1.653341614846e+12,
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/login"
    },
    {
    "action": "pageChange",
    "dom": "",
    "timestamp": 1.653341626442e+12,
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/login"
   }
  ]
 }
```

If i find other or better methods, I'll definitely share..
I hope this solution helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that. You can specify the object nesting in form of string in the query.

```
await MyModel.find({ 'data.objectKey.items.item': 'text I want to find' }).exec();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think it is exactly what I need. I made and update of the question